# EventListener issues for images in ScrollableView for IOS Appcelerator

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have added some images in two different views & placed them inside a ScrollableView. On click of images, EventListener is not getting executed. This code works perfectly for Android(appcelerator) but for IOS it's not working.

Scroll & other Events are working fine. The problem seems with items placed in ScrollableView.

```
  var dataView = Ti.UI.createView({
    layout : 'horizontal',
    top : '0'
});

var textHolderView = Ti.UI.createView({
    layout : 'vertical',
    width : '50%'
});

var iconView = Ti.UI.createView({
    layout : 'horizontal',
    width : '24.5%'
});

var header = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "Some Text",
    font : {
        fontSize : '12dp',
        fontFamily : 'OpenSans-Semibold',
        fontWeight : 'normal'
    },
    height : '38dp',
    left : '15%',
    color : '#000',
    width : '85%',
    touchEnabled : false    
});

var image1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : "/images/individual.png",
    height : '18dp',
    left : '5dp',
    width : '13%',
    top : '25%'
});

var slideOptionsView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : "#1268b3",
    layout : "horizontal"
});

var img_activity = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : "/images/activity_temp.png",
    height : "30dp",
    width : "70dp",
    left : "10%",
    top : "15dp",
    touchEnabled : true
});

textHolderView.add(header);
iconView.add(image1);
dataView.add(textHolderView);
dataView.add(iconView);

slideOptionsView.add(img_activity);

var scroll = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
    views : [dataView, slideOptionsView],
    showPagingControl : false,
});


// Event Listeners on click for above images
 img_activity.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     alert("img_activity");
 });

image1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert("image1");
});

$.someView.add(scroll); 

$.index.open();
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can use image module

Comment: It looks like you've found something that works differently across platforms where it shouldn't need to. Thanks! This might be https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20493. If it's not, then please create a new ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Above issue is solved. https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23150 is having a PR.